# Posting data to a SQL Table via vb.net Form with an onClick Submit button

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to VB.net and I'm working on a project in Visual Studio 2015. In one of my application's tab I'm trying to INSERT new records into a SQL Table via  form post, but once I click the button nothing happens and no new records are added. My current code is below, any help would be great! Thanks:

**Contact.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="Contact" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Contact.aspx.vb" Inherits="Contact" %>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<br />
<p style="font-size: 15px;">Fill out the form below and click SUBMIT once completed:</p>
<form id="submitData" method="post">
<fieldset>
  <p><label for="Term">Term:</label>
  <input type="text" name="Term" required />*
  </p>

  <p><label for="genre">Definition:</label>
     <input type="text" name="Definition" required />*
  </p>

  <p><label for="year">Long Description:</label>
     <textarea rows="3" type="text" name="LongDescription" required></textarea>*
  </p>
  <p><label for="title">Category:</label>
     <select name="Category" style="width: 312px; height: 31px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 1.2em;">
      <option selected="selected">
      <option value="Branding">Branding</option>
      <option value="Business">Business</option>
      <option value="Business Management">Business Management</option>
      <option value="CRM">CRM</option>
      <option value="Communications">Communications</option>
      <option value="Dental Health">Dental Health</option>
      <option value="Education">Education</option>
      <option value="General">General</option>
      <option value="Governmental">Governmental</option>
      <option value="IT">IT</option>
      <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
      <option value="Nutrition">Nutrition</option>
      <option value="State Laws">State Laws</option>
      <option value="Other">Other...</option>
    </select>
  </p>
    <p><label for="title">Date Loaded:</label>
     <input type="text" name="DateLoaded" id="datepicker" required />*
  </p>
    <p><label for="title">Provided By (your name):</label>
     <input type="text" name="ProvidedBy" required />*
  </p>
    <p><label for="title">Department:</label>
     <input type="text" name="Department" required />*
  </p>
    <p><label for="title">Internal Expert or SME for this topic:</label>
     <input type="text" name="SME" />
  </p>

  <p><asp:Button ID="buttonSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="buttonSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" /></p>
</fieldset>

 </form>
<br />
<p>* Please allow between 24 to 48 hours to have your term added to the dictionary.</p>
<br />
<a style="font-size: 16px; font: bold; background-color: black; color:white; text-decoration:none; padding:5px;" href="Default.aspx">Back</a>
</body>
</asp:Content>
```

**Contact.aspx.vb**

```
Partial Class Contact

Inherits Page

Protected Sub buttonSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim sqlConnection1 As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("ConnectionString HERE")

    Dim cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table_terms (Term, Definition, LongDescription, Category, DateLoaded, ProvidedBy, Department, SME) VALUES (Term, Definition, LongDescription, Category, DateLoaded, ProvidedBy, Department, SME)"
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

    sqlConnection1.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlConnection1.Close()

End Sub

End Class
```

Any hint would be great. Thanks a lot!

M.C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command text is jacked up.  Strings need to be quoted, for instance.  Try running the statement in SSMS.  If it doesn't work from there it's not going to work from .Net.

Also, what you're doing is a security issue.  Use stored procedures and pass values as parameters.  Building up a statement to execute in .Net will lead both to worse performance and injection vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @btberry. Applying those changes